# Is this the wrong use of Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm working on an MVC app with some colleagues. The Controllers all have a ServiceFactory injected in to them using Unity...

```
public HomeController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
{
   Services = serviceFactory 
   // Where Services is a property of the Controller
}
```

Now, I'm writing a number of ViewModels and some of these ViewModels need to access objects from a number of Services. So, I've got a pattern like this...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(IServiceFactory services)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

and my Controllers contain code like this...

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewNodel(Services)
    // ...
}
```

Some of my colleagues suggest that this isn't the correct use of DI but seem unable to articulate why that might be.

Are they right? If so why?

Comment: I don't agree with your colleagues. You use correctly the DI pattern. You inject the dependency you have in the constructor of your Controller and subsequently you use it in your methods.

Comment: Your use of DI is correct, but your use of it inside a ViewModel isn't (in my opinion).

Comment: A bit late but why inject a factory when you could inject the service itself? Unless the service is called factory and you should change the name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that your colleagues are throwing red flags is because you are successfully practicing DI with your services injection, yet you are newing up an instance of MyViewModel inside of your controller action, which "hides" the implementation details from the outside.

Now, that said, since this controller should not be consumed directly from other code but rather from the web, you could make the argument that this is acceptable.  My personal preference is that since you've already started injecting dependencies, don't stop now!

**EDIT:**

As James has mentioned in the comments, it would be far better to resolve your viewmodel instance via an independent, injected factory.  That way you could resolve multiple views within the same controller class.

```
private readonly IViewModelFactory _factory;
public HomeController(IViewModelFactory factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
    var model = _factory.GetViewModelInstance(); 
    // Where Services is a property of the Controller
}
```

When registering

```
IMyViewModelFactory
```

to your concrete class, resolve the injection of IServiceFactory in your container, highlighting it as an injected dependency.

```
public ViewModelFactory(IServiceFactory factory)
```

Comment: I disagree, creating a new concrete view model here is fine given view models are purposely built for a 1-1 mapping with a view. DI on view models, again only my opinion, is completely overkill.

Comment: @James I understand your reservations and I share a bit of that concern in my answer.  That said, DI "purists" will insist that you inject "all the way down", which is most likely why his colleagues are balking at the approach.  Also, let's remember that we may be misinterpreting his correct use of the word "ViewModel".  In this case, it really could be a binding model being injected into a view directly or it could be a massive BL abstraction that performs complex calculations.

Comment: I get the point you are making, perhaps a better example would be injecting an `IViewModelFactory` instance rather than injecting a view as an individual dependency (I imagine there would be multiple views in a single controller).

Comment: @james is correct, we have a number of different ViewModels in any given Controller.

Comment: @James that would be an excellent alternative and probably the better course of action in this case.

Comment: @David, the ViewModel is something of a BL abstraction. I simply find the idea of doing all of the BL work in the Controller too odd to be comfortable with.

Comment: @StuartHemming I absolutely agree.  One of my first refactors with MVC projects gone wrong is typically to refactor the Controller into a thin, manageable API.  Hopefully my updated answer better reflects James feedback and your thought process.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the clarification; I will investigate the possibility of creating a ViewModel factory.

Answer (score 3):

Looks right to me. The `ViewModels` have a dependency on some services. So rather than instantiate those services inside of the `ViewModel`, you *inject* them in via the constructor. A pretty straightforward case of DI.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how your view of design, but what's going wrong in your application IMO is that you mix data with behavior. The view models that you should supply the view with should be DTOs; pure data objects. You don't want those objects to have any behavior, because this hides the logic from the application. All logic that is executed when the view renders should be as simple as possible. Not only makes this reasoning about the application code simpler, it prevents you from having to write automated tests for your view (which is an absolute pain).

Letting view models be anything else than simple DTOs breaks down rather quickly, when you use the view model as 'post-back model' as well (which is very common and convenient). MVC can't model bind your complex view model unless you write a custom binder that injects those dependencies into it; or at least tell MVC how to construct that type. This is highly unpractical and leads to a lot of extra code for each view model. Although this problem can be fixed by defining a seperate 'post-only' view model, this again leads to duplicate code. These two models will get out-of-sync rather quickly (I speak from experience in this).

Since you mix behavior in your view model, you are forced to either do dependency injection manually in your controller (as you do now), or you need to extract this code to a factory. Both have their downsides.

Injecting those dependencies as you do now, pollutes the controller with injection code; something it should not be concerned about. A constructor should be an implementation detail (that only the class itself and the composition root is concerned about), but now every time the constructor of your view model changes, this change bubbles up to the controller.

Extracting this into a factory might solve that problem, but will force you to write a factory for each controller. Although some containers contain features to auto-generate these factories for you, you still have this extra abstraction in your code; an abstraction that wasn't needed if you kept your view model a humble DTO.

So in general you should follow this rule:

> Create object graphs of stateless services and build them early. After that, pass pure data through the graph.

So in your case, the view model is the data. Data should not depend on services; services should depend on data. You let your service (your controller) create that data (the view model) and pass it on (returning it to the view).